# Next Auth v5 not getting redirected after login

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next-auth

I am using credentials provider with token rotation with my custom backend for authentication in my next app

Here is my auth.ts

```
async function refreshToken(
  token: JWT,
  {
    refreshToken,
    expiresIn,
  }: {
    refreshToken: string;
    expiresIn: number;
  }
) {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post(`${BaseConfig.backendUrl}/auth/refresh`, {
      token: refreshToken,
      expiresIn,
    });

    const response = await res.data.data;

    return {
      ...token,
      accessToken: {
        token: response.accessToken.token,
        expiresIn: response.accessToken.expiresIn,
      },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      ...token,
      error: "RefreshAccessTokenError",
    };
  }
}

export const {
  handlers: { GET, POST },
  auth,
  signIn,
  signOut,
  unstable_update,
} = NextAuth({
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/login",
    error: "/auth/error",
  },
  ...authConfig,
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token }) {
      // @ts-ignore
      session.user = token.user;
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      session.refreshToken = token.refreshToken;
      if (token?.error) session.error = token.error;

      return Promise.resolve(session);
    },
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.user = user.user;
        token.refreshToken = user.refreshToken;
        token.accessToken = user.accessToken;
      }

      if (new Date().getTime() > token.accessToken.expiresIn)
        return await refreshToken(token, {
          refreshToken: token.refreshToken.token,
          expiresIn: token.refreshToken.expiresIn,
        });

      return Promise.resolve(token);
    },
  },

  session: { strategy: "jwt" },
  secret: process.env.AUTH_SECRET,
});
```

```
export default {
  providers: [
    Credentials({
      async authorize(credentials) {
        if (!credentials?.email || !credentials?.password) return null;

        const { email, password } = credentials;

        const res = await axios.post(`${BaseConfig.backendUrl}/auth/login`, {
          email,
          password,
        });

        if (res.status !== 200) {
          return null;
        }

        const user = res.data.data;
        return Promise.resolve(user);
      },
    }),
  ],
} satisfies NextAuthConfig;
```

I have modified the next-auth session jwt and user types as follows

```
import NextAuth, { DefaultSession } from "next-auth";
import { MainUser } from "./user";

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface User {
    user: MainUser;
    accessToken: {
      expiresIn: number;
      token: string;
    };
    refreshToken: {
      expiresIn: number;
      token: string;
    };
  }

  interface Session {
    user: MainUser & DefaultSession["user"];
    accessToken: {
      expiresIn: number;
      token: string;
    };
    refreshToken: {
      expiresIn: number;
      token: string;
    };
    error?: string;
  }
}

import { JWT } from "next-auth/jwt";

declare module "next-auth/jwt" {
  interface JWT {
    user: MainUser;
    accessToken: {
      expiresIn: number;
      token: string;
    };
    refreshToken: {
      expiresIn: number;
      token: string;
    };
    error?: string;
  }
}
```

Im using login with server actions

```
"use server";

import { signIn } from "@/auth";
import { DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT } from "@/config/routes";
import { LoginSchema } from "@/schemas/auth-schemas";
import { AuthError } from "next-auth";
import { z } from "zod";

export const login = async (
  values: z.infer<typeof LoginSchema>,
  callbackUrl?: string | null
) => {
  const { email, password } = values;
  try {
    await signIn("credentials", {
      email,
      password,
      redirectTo: callbackUrl || DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof AuthError) {
      switch (error.type) {
        case "CredentialsSignin":
          return { error: "Invalid credentials!" };

        default:
          return { error: "Internal server error!" };
      }
    }
  }
};
```

the problem is i am not getting redirected to the "/dashboard page but as soon as i manually reloads it takes me to it.

i should directly redirect me to dashboard as soon as i login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your server action you need to throw the error in case it is not an AuthError:

```
"use server";

import { signIn } from "@/auth";
import { DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT } from "@/config/routes";
import { LoginSchema } from "@/schemas/auth-schemas";
import { AuthError } from "next-auth";
import { z } from "zod";

export const login = async (
  values: z.infer<typeof LoginSchema>,
  callbackUrl?: string | null
) => {
  const { email, password } = values;
  try {
    await signIn("credentials", {
      email,
      password,
      redirectTo: callbackUrl || DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof AuthError) {
      switch (error.type) {
        case "CredentialsSignin":
          return { error: "Invalid credentials!" };

        default:
          return { error: "Internal server error!" };
      }
    }
    throw error;
  }
};
```

Yep it is a strange way to do redirection...